# How do I parent the head and the tail of a bone to two different meshes/empties?

Tags: rigging, armature, motion-capture

I want to copy the movement of my hand to blender. I tracked some points on my hand and linked the tracks to empties in the 3d viewport. Then I made bones between the markers. I tried parenting and use the "copy location" constraint to make the bone move with the markers. The problem is that if you try to copy the location of two markers, the bone will only move with one. I need the head and tail to stay at two different markers and follow them both. I hope you understand me.

[image: A screenshot to make it more clear...]

thank you for your help

Comment: My instinct is that you will need some flavor of Inverse Kinematic constraint.  http://blender-manual-i18n.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/rigging/posing/inverse_kinematics.html

Comment: If the bone should follow both markers, it could be forced to _deform_ itself (streching)... or it should _track_ both markers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible way using bones "stretching", in pose mode,  to their top/bottom empties (trackers), not sure you want this, but, anyway here is how it works:

[image]

I've set an armature copy location to the bottom tracker, so the head of the bottom bone follows it. But the pose mode contraint stretches to the top tracker, too.